# dict from columns of pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tuples

How to create a dictionary from columns of pandas dataframe. here is test code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c0': ['A','A','B'],
    'c1': ['b','c','d'],
    'c2': [1, 3,4],
    'c3': [5,7,8]})
```

Output:

```
  c0 c1  c2  c3
0  A  b   1   5
1  A  c   3   7
2  B  d   4   8
```

I would like to obtain a dictionary from, say, key:(c0, c1)  and value:(c2)

```
{('A', 'b'): 1, ('A', 'c'): 3, ('B', 'd'): 4}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) - `MutiIndex` creates `tuples`:

```
print (df.set_index(['c0','c1'])['c2'].to_dict())
{('B', 'd'): 4, ('A', 'b'): 1, ('A', 'c'): 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it

```
dict(zip(zip(df['c0'], df['c1']), df['c2']))
```